# Playframework project with submodules in docker (incorrect URL)

Tags: docker, playframework

I created playframework project with 2 submodules

1. Submodule 'core'. Available under http://localhost:9000/core/... E.g. http://localhost:9000/core/users
2. Submodule 'chat'. Available under http://localhost:9000/chat/... http://localhost:9000/chat/messages

I created docker image by

```
sbt docker:publishLocal
```

When I start the app inside docker, my modules are available by URL without module name. E.g.

http://DOCKER_IP:9000/users (must be http://DOCKER_IP:9000/core/users )

http://DOCKER_IP:9000/messages (must be http://DOCKER_IP:9000/chat/messages )

So it does not work correctly. How can I make play in docker to use correct URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Docker is not responsible for designing your URLs or even mapping them, it only maps the port (9000).

Playframework web conf is what you are looking for.